# Python writing to file from multiple separate Python processes, do I have to lock file?

Tags: python, file, python-3.8

I have a Python script that is running in a number of different Kubernetes pods at all times (minimum 1, max ~100 at the same time).

These processes are largely independent of each other, except that at one point, they have to write to the same file (last_appended.txt) in the following fashion:

```
with open(filepath, 'w') as file:
    file.write(str(int(time.timestamp())))
```

I am wondering if I have to do any sort of locking on this file or if this is such a minimal operation that this is not necessary?

If I would want to lock the file, I have found the following code to enable this:

```
with open(filepath, 'w') as file:
        fcntl.flock(file, fcntl.LOCK_EX)
        file.write(str(int(time.timestamp())))
        fcntl.flock(file, fcntl.LOCK_UN)
```

However, I wonder if this is enough to let my processes run smoothly, or that I maybe have to write some sort of try/except loop when a lock is encountered by a process.

Summarising, my question is two-fold:

1. Would I have to lock the file at all, or is this such a small operation that it can be done by multiple processes without crashing, and
2. If no, would my solution to the multiple processes writing to the file be sufficient?

Comment: You have bigger problems here. What does it mean for a process to write to the file? Each process will just overwrite the file. Did you mean to append to the file?

Comment: I really think you should go back to the drawing board. Maybe use a database, have each pod having its own file and combine them when needed, just print it and take the logs, make each row an independent file or create a seperate service to control it. Having multiple pods editing the same file at the same time is a resipy for disaster and data loss

Comment: Hmmm yeah I might have to reconsider the approach. I however need a quick solution for this at present... Or are you saying this is not possible in any way like this? Overwriting the file is not a problem but the 'str(int(time.timestamp())' write has to be at the top of the file, so appending is actually not an option since this inserts at the bottom of the file.

Comment: I don't know but I have had my fair share of database deadlocks to respect this. And furthermore it is very difficult to test what will happen when you suddently have 100 processes writing to the same file. You might up end up having bad surprises when you sends this to production

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unrelated: using `w` mode in this context is weird, do not you mean `a` mode here?

---

As you are using `fcntl` I shall assume a Unix-like system here

If you do not use locks, you have what is called a *race condition*. It means that under small load, the risk of problem is close to 0, but it could increase under higher load. This us something that sysadmins hate, because it leads to non reproducible problems.

A lock costs indeed some resources, but under normal load (where the non locking version would not experience any problems), there would be no contention on that lock, so it should not be noticeable. Under heavy load, it would prevent garbled messages if two processes tried to write at the same time.

If you want to prevent contention under heavy load, you could wait with a short timeout. It is easy on a number of systems or requires explicitely calling `alarm` on some others. If the lock could be acquired, just proceed with writing to the file. Else, skip that writing and if possible log (elsewhere) the error condition for later analysis.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that the 'str(int(time.timestamp())' has to be written at the top of the file for the rest of the process to run. However, I might be able to rewrite the process as to enable appending to the file. I guess this would would take away the lock problem as the file is not actually overwritten but appended to wouldn't it?

Comment: @Tim: No it would not. If two processes try to write the same file at the same time, the result is not guaranteed.

Comment: I think this gives me the info I need. I will implement it your way

Answer (score 1):

You need to lock the entire process of writing to the file:

```py
fcntl.flock(file, fcntl.LOCK_EX)
with open(filepath, 'w') as file:
    file.write(str(int(time.timestamp())))
fcntl.flock(file, fcntl.LOCK_UN)
```

Comment: I was attempted by this one... until I realized that you need the file to be opened before being able to lock it. This code uses file before it is defined...

Comment: You need to a mutex that the two processes can share.

Comment: I do not know enough Kubernetes to know whether it is native, possible or impossible, so I did not speak of it.

Comment: Ok, perhaps you could create a lock on a file you don't care about, and inside that write to the file you *do* care about.

Comment: But again, for the lock to be useful, several processes should be able to open that same file at the same time...